# Music can't stop using music.pause()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

`music.pause();` seems not to be working in my code. When I click at the play button (the button is made using a box in html 5 canvas) it can play the music, but when I click at the stop button, it doesn't work. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
var X = 0;
var Y = 0;
var mouse_click = false;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){  
    var boundRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    X =  e.pageX - boundRect.left  ;
    Y = e.pageY ;
    console.log(e.pageX+" "+e.pageY);
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
    mouse_click = true;
    var music_canon = new Audio("Assets/Music/Canon.mp3");

    if((X>=5 && X<=40) && (Y>=500 && Y<=560))  // for play button
    {
        music_canon.play();
    }

    else if ((X>=45 && X<=82) && (Y>=500 && Y<=560)) // for stop button
    {
        music_canon.pause(); //this code is not working, it's not stop the music
    }
```

the music still keep going when I click at the stop button.

Comment: on each mousedown event you start a new audio. So the next time you click you (on either button) the pause or play instruction goes to a new instance of Audio(). Move that var outside your eventlistener

Comment: I rolled back your edit on the title. You mark your question as solved by accepting the answer that best solved your problem. We don't want to pollute the titles as they are used for searching.

Comment: sorry, i'm still new in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're creating a new element every time. Instead, create `music_canon` outside of the function and reference the same instance every time.

```
var music_canon = new Audio("Assets/Music/Canon.mp3");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
     if((X >= 5 && X <= 40) && (Y >= 500 && Y <= 560)) {
         music_canon.play();
     } else if ((X > =45 && X <= 82) && (Y >= 500 && Y <= 560)) {
         music_canon.pause();
     }
});
```